# Should I use Electrum Wallet OR Bitcoin Core as my website's payment gateway?

Tags: bitcoin-core, electrum, full-node, payment, website-integration

I'm a developer who is building a website that need to process Bitcoin payment requests. So I need a payment gateway.

In my last project, I used Electrum wallet as payment gateway but my last project doesn't have too much bitcoin payment requests, and electrum works fine.
But I'm afraid of electrum's limitations and **I'm not sure it's a good idea to use electrum when processing lots of payment requests.**

**Bitcoin Core runs bitcoin node but it takes too much disk space (full node) or CPU usage (prune mode)** and I'm afraid it's not a good idea too.

So please tell me which one preforms better as a website's payment gateway, and why. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: Core would be objectively better because you'd be running a full node, as opposed to electrum, which is a SPV wallet.

Comment: Thank you @RutgerVersteegden but may be core eats more CPU but I'll try that because core is definitely more safer than electrum

Comment: Btcpayserver is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Coinbase commerce](https://commerce.coinbase.com/docs/api) as a solution for Bitcoin payments on my website. I like them because the fees are very low and the API is very stable.

Comment: Thank you, but I've decided not to use a third-party API which has KYC & less speed:) Good luck!